# Is it possible to use scalatra's unquoted HTML literal string syntax in sinatra?

Tags: html, ruby, scala, sinatra, scalatra

I would like to use this style in sinatra:

```
get("/") {
  <html>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      Say <a href="hello-scalate">hello to Scalate</a>.
    </body>
  </html>
}
```

http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/first-project.html#toc_64

But it wasn't clear to me whether this is possible to use unquoted literal HTML strings in the body of the get function.

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd quote the section you mean in the body of your question. As is, we're going to have to guess what you mean exactly, or wander off to look at that link. Plus, *when* that link dies, your question is going to be pretty worthless.

Comment: In Scalatra (not Sinatra), you can indeed use bare "HTML" (actually XML) like this -- not because Scalatra goes out of its way to support it, but because XML literals are a thing in Scala. http://grahamhackingscala.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/xml-generation-with-scala.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby and Sinatra don't support that exact format because it'd be a syntax error. You have to quote the string containing the markup somehow, otherwise Ruby will complain. But, you can do that with just a little addition of Ruby code:

```
require 'sinatra'

get("/") {
  %{
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        Say <a href="hello-scalate">hello to Scalate</a>.
      </body>
    </html>
  }
}
```

You could do it this way too:

```
require 'sinatra'

get("/") {
  return <<EOT
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    Say <a href="hello-scalate">hello to Scalate</a>.
  </body>
</html>
EOT
}
```

One way or the other the content has to be "stringified".

This is one of the things I really like about Sinatra. It's a great prototyping tool for web services. Whatever is returned by the handler goes to the browser. If it's not HTML then you can easily specify what type it is using the `content_type` method and the MIME type for the content, then return that content.

Comment: The second example looks like a here document. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's just another way to copy content into a string.